# Combining transformation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Sorry for dumb question and possibly duplicate but I can't get my head around order of combining transformation matrices. I've read that transformation matrices should be combined by multiplication and when multiplying transformations are "applied" from right to left.

Let’s say there are two matrices $T$ and $S$ where $T$ is translation matrix and $S$ is scaling matrix like this:
$$T=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&3\\\\0&1&2\\\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$S=\begin{bmatrix}0.5&0&0\\\\0&0.5&0\\\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$M_1 = T \times S = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&3\\\\0&1&2\\\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}0.5&0&0\\\\0&0.5&0\\\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.5&0&3\\\\0&0.5&2\\\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$M_2 = S \times T = \begin{bmatrix}0.5&0&0\\\\0&0.5&0\\\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}1&0&3\\\\0&1&2\\\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.5&0&1.5\\\\0&0.5&1\\\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

In a case of $M_1$ the translation is preserved so it seems that we have first translated and then scaled. In a case of $M_2$ it is the other way around.

So it seems that the order of transformations being applied in resulting matrix is from left to right. Is this correct or the way I'm thinking about the problem is completely wrong?

Comment: No. In $M_1 x$ (x is column) you first scaled then translated, if $x^{T} M_1$ then you are right, first translated then scaled. (But note that the practice here advice to do multiplication from the left. i.e. $M_1 x$. And also note, that if you want to get similar results, $M_1 x \neq x^{T} M_1$, it rather $\sim x^{T} (M_1)^T$).

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. By $M_1x$ you mean multiplication of $M_1$ with column vector $x$ and it's different to have $T \times S \times x$ and $x^T \times T \times S$ . Possibly I edit the question to clarify my misunderstanding. Maybe the question can be deleted if you think it doesn't makes sense.

Comment: No. Its clearly make sense. I just wanted to give some hint for understanding. Generally $S\times T \neq T\times S$, and even $S\times T \times x $ (x column) $\neq x^{Tr} \times T \times S$.